# Creating only one byte with struct.pack

Tags: python, hex, output

I wrote a python script that uses `struct.pack()` to convert a decimal number into a hex string.

For example:

```
struct.pack('>h', 1024) => '\x04\x00'
```

The problem is, when I enter a number below 256 it still creates a string that consists of two bytes.

For example:

```
struct.pack('>h', 20) => '\x00\x14'
```

That is a problem for me because for a number below 256 I can only work with one byte. That means for 20 decimal I would like to generate the output '\x14'.

Is there some way to force `struct.pack()` to do that or do I need a different function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'>h'` stands for big endian two bytes short integer.
If you want to get a single byte unsiged integer you have to use `'>B'`:

```
struct.pack('>B', 20) => '\x14'
```

You can check the format character in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters), but the most used ones are:

- `c`: char, string of lenght 1, 1 byte
- `b`: signed char, integer, 1 byte
- `B`: unsigned char, integer, 1 byte
- `h`: short, integer, 2 bytes
- `H`: unisgned short, integer, 2 bytes
- `i`: int, integer, 4 bytes
- `I`: unsigned int, integer, 4 bytes
- `f`: float, float, 4 bytes
- `d`: double, float, 8 bytes

The endianess (`'>'`) determines the byte positions, but for 1 byte is not important.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just tested it and it works :)
I tried a few others format characters before but it seems like I skipped the B format character. ^^"